# Folium and the meridians 180 & -180

Tags: python, folium

I would like to plot with Folium a flight between Tokyo and Los Angeles over the Pacific ocean and centre the map on the Pacific ocean.
But between the meridians 180 and -180, the points are not properly connected (see fig. 1). What I want is illustrated in Fig. 2.

**Fig.1:**
[image]

**Fig.2:**
[image]

**Code:**

```
import folium
points = [[35.7652, 140.3855], [40, 180], [40, -180], [33.9425, -118.4080]]
map = folium.Map(location=[0, 180], zoom_start=2)
folium.PolyLine(points, color="red", weight=2.5).add_to(map)
map.save("myMap.html")
```

Comment: Could cheat a bit :-) .  `points = [[35.7652, 140.3855], [33.9425, 360 -118.4080]]`

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this will draw a line between my two points across North America, Atlantic Ocean, Europe and Asia instead of the Pacific ocean.

Comment: I didn't do a good job pointing it out, but it shouldn't.  I threw a `360` into your LA long

Comment: @ Bob Haffner, I apologize,  I didn't notice the `360`! It works like a charm! Thank you very much!

Comment: No worries, glad it worked.  You should consider adding the solution as an answer

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Bob Haffner for his useful help. The trick consists to add `360` for negative longitudes.

```
import folium
points = [[35.7652, 140.3855], [40, 180], [40, 360 -180], [33.9425, 360 -118.4080]]
map = folium.Map(location=[0, 180], zoom_start=2)
folium.PolyLine(points, color="red", weight=2.5).add_to(map)
map.save("myMap.html")
```

[image]